# Defining Probability in GAMS

Tags: gams-math

Does anybody know how to define the below probability in GAMS?

```
 Z=P(x<y)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the cumulative distribution function (CDF). To calculate P(x < y), simply input the value of y into the CDF. For example, the cumulative distribution function for a uniform distribution U(0,1) is f(x) = x. The probability P(x < 0.4) is f(0.4) = 0.4.

This works for more complex CDFs as well, as long as they can be expressed in GAMS.